# Can't open Steam (You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run)

Tags: 64-bit, 14.10, steam

I for some reason can't open Steam. It worked for a while before but it suddenly stopped working. Here's the error that shows up:

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libglib-2.0.so.0
libglib-2.0.so.0
libglib-2.0.so.0
libglib-2.0.so.0
libglib-2.0.so.0
libglib-2.0.so.0
libdbus-1.so.3
libglib-2.0.so.0
libbz2.so.1.0
libglib-2.0.so.0
libglib-2.0.so.0
libglib-2.0.so.0
libglib-2.0.so.0
libwrap.so.0
libdbus-1.so.3
```

Comment: Running an AMD graphics card for anyone who's wondering.

Answer (score 0):

Steam needs some 32-bit libraries in order to work.

Install the following libraries with package manager tool (apt-get, aptitude, synaptic, etc)

```
libglib2.0-0:i386
libdbus-1-3:i386
libwrap0:i386
libbz2-1.0:i386
```

Pay attention to `i386` as it means 32-bit version.

Comment: After running this, it did in fact lessen the errors but I still got one: "You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libbz2.so.1.0"